# How to properly SQL-injection-proof my query in objective c

Tags: objective-c, xcode, sqlite, xcode4.3

I have one function in my objective c code that updates a SQLite table column with notes entered by the user in a text field. I want to make sure that I'm doing this properly so that there are no security issues or problems in general. Here is my code, is there something I can do to make this more secure, or is it already OK?

```
sqlite3_stmt *stmt=nil;
sqlite3 *cruddb;

//insert
const char *sql = "UPDATE Peaks SET notes=? where ID=?";

//Open db
sqlite3_open([path UTF8String], &cruddb);
sqlite3_prepare_v2(cruddb, sql, -1, &stmt, NULL);
sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, [self.viewNotes.text UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, 2, [self.detailItem ID]);

sqlite3_step(stmt);
sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
sqlite3_close(cruddb);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are already SQL injection safe because you are passing user input through **sqlite3_bind_text** and **sqlite3_bind_int**.

Comment: Great! Thanks! Just want to make sure I'm not making any stupid mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

Good question! It looks like you are already doing the right thing by binding your values rather than doing something stupid like using `[NSString stringWithFormat]` to construct the SQL statement.

Comment: Great! Thanks! Just want to make sure I'm not making any stupid mistakes.